# Getting c++11 auto initialization syntax right

Tags: c++11

I am newbie programmer in C++ (but a veteran programmer in other languages) and I am trying to use "Modern C++" in my code.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong here, trying to initialize an istream from a boost::asio::streambuf:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio/streambuf.hpp>

class A {
  public:
    void foo();
  private:
    boost::asio::streambuf cmdStreamBuf_{};
};

void A::foo() {
  std::istream is1{&cmdStreamBuf_}; // works
  auto is2 = std::istream{&cmdStreamBuf_}; // does not compile
}
```

I get this error:

```
try.cpp:13:41: error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_istream<char>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<char>&)'
```

I am not trying to copy; I thought I was constructing an std::istream!

Comment: You are probably using a version of libstdc++ that doesn't have movable streams.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, but the problem is at compile time.  I have edited my post to say that explicitly and to show the error I am getting.

Comment: When you initialize a variable at declaration, you are implicitly calling the copy-constructor (or if supported, the "move" constructor).

Comment: That's the exact issue. The `auto is2 = std::istream{&cmdStreamBuf_};` syntax technically constructs a temporary `std::istream` and then moves/copies it into `is2`; the move/copy can and will be elided by the compiler, but a move/copy constructor must still be available. Streams are not copyable, and your standard library didn't provide a move constructor either, so it fails to compile. Since `std::istream`'s move constructor would be protected even if it were there, you can't use this syntax at all.

Comment: @T.C. The move ctor of `std::istream` is protected: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/basic_istream

Comment: You could use `auto&& is2 = ...` or, you know, just construct it in-place.

Comment: @dyp Good point, still he'd get a different error if the move ctor were there.

Comment: @T.C. [Indeed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5e9098b271ace7a)

Comment: @T.C. Okay.  Hmm.  I thought that `auto var = type{...}` was syntatic sugar for `type var{...}`.  I guess I'll throw out the use of auto in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all the answers were in the comments, I thought I'd finish this off by doing an official answer myself.

I am using a c++ library that doesn't have movable streams, and this matters because

```
auto is2 = std::istream{&cmdStreamBuf_};
```

creates a new `std::istream` and then initializes `is2` with that rvalue (temporary object).  It initializes it by calling the copy constructor or the move constructor.  My c++ library apparently does not have either of these constructors, therefore the call fails.

I had originally thought that

```
auto varname = typename{...};
```

was the conceptually the same as

```
typename varname{...};
```

but it is not.  So, this is an instance where you can't use `auto` to create a variable.

(sigh) And I was really hyped on using `auto` everywhere.

Comment: [Back to the Basics! Essentials of Modern C++ Style](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/CPP/C-PP-Con-2014/0010-Back-to-the-Basics-Essentials-of-Modern-C-Style) Don't know exactly where in the presentation but Herb Sutter has an entire chapter here advocating the use of `auto` almost everywhere. It touches a lot of points, including your case.

Comment: @bolov I know; that's why I started down this path.  Maybe I missed something in that presentation...

Comment: no, I didn't put the link to counter your answer, I put it because it is interesting as a whole. (in it, indeed one example where you can't use auto is where you have a non-movable type)